# Get attribute with file_get_contents PHP

Tags: php, html, get, file-get-contents

I have a sql query that I store in a variable and I displayed. I get the contents of this with file_get_contents from another file, I would like to recover some of this code (which is html) in order to make link. More precisely retrieve the id.
My api.php

```
$base = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('administrations', $base);

if(isset($_GET['cp']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT NOM_organisme, ID_organisme
            FROM organismes
            WHERE code_postal LIKE "%'.$_GET['cp'].'%"
            ORDER BY NOM_organisme;';

    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('SQL Error !<br>'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
}

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req))
{
    echo '<p id="'.$data['ID_organisme'].'"'.
         $data['NOM_organisme'].'</br>'.
         $data['ID_organisme'].'</p></br>';
}
```

I want to get the `id="I WANT THIS"`.

And my index.php (part of my code that retrieves the contents).

```
if(isset($_POST['cp']))
{
    $api = "http://mywebsite.fr/api.php?cp=".$_POST['cp'];
    $var = file_get_contents($api);
    echo $var;
}
```

How can I get the `id=""` in my index.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at php get documentation. you need to link to your script with url parameters and access them in your php code.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
    echo '<a href="?id='.$data['ID_organisme'].'">'.$data['NOM_organisme'].'</br>'.$data['ID_organisme'].'</a></br>';
```

php

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $api = "http://mywebsite.fr/api.php?cp=".$_GET['id'];
    $var = file_get_contents($api);
    echo $var;
}
```

if you dont want to use url parameter you can use post values

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your trying to do, but dont find it logical without knowing the purpose of this tiny code :)

Do you have a link or some sort?

Basicly what i should do is:

```
$base = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('administrations', $base);

if(isset($_POST['cp']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT NOM_organisme, ID_organisme FROM organismes WHERE code_postal LIKE "%'.$_GET['cp'].'%" ORDER BY NOM_organisme;';
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('SQL Error !<br>'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req))
    {
        echo '<p id="'.$data['ID_organisme'].'"'.$data['NOM_organisme'].'</br>'.$data['ID_organisme'].'</p></br>';
    }
} else {
        echo 'show something else';
}
```

Comment: No, i didn't have link,
This is all of my code in api.php before the php code
`<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <meta name="Jimmy"/>

 <title>Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="index.php">

<p>
    <h3>Code postal</h3>
    <input type="text" name="cp"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer"/>
</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
` . And this is all of my code.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you are

1. Sending a GET request in *index.php* using *file_get_contents()* to your website.
2. The website (*api.php*) performs an SQL query and prints the result in HTML.
3. *index.php* takes this HTML output and stores it in the variable *$var*.
4. You want to retrieve **all** values contained inside the id attribute of the paragraph.

In this case, you probably want to use regular expressions. [preg_match_all](http://de.php.net/preg_match_all) seems to be appropriate. It should work for you like this:

```
$out = array();
preg_match_all("/id=\"([^\"]*?)\"/U", $var, $out);
foreach ($out as $value) {
  echo 'I found some id ' . htmlspecialchars($out[$value][2]) . '<br />';
}
```

And additionally:

1. A decent HTML parser would be much more appropriate in this case (eg. it would not match id="X" in flow text).
2. Your PHP code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injections).
3. You should sanitize plain text to HTML [appropriately](http://de.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to display your API reply as a JSON-string, this is much more convenient.

If you still want to use your api.php, you first need to close your opening paragraph! You did forget a '>'!

```
echo '<p id="'.$data['ID_organisme'].'">'.
     $data['NOM_organisme'].'</br>'.
     $data['ID_organisme'].'</p></br>';
```

Then you need to parse your paragraph.
You can do it like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['cp']))
{
    $api = "http://mywebsite.fr/api.php?cp=".$_POST['cp'];
    $var = file_get_contents($api);
    preg_match("@<p id='(.*)'@", $var, $matches);
    id = $matches[1];

    echo $id;
}
```